# pass click event between two page by localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I want to take a click event from **2nd page** . **1st page** have a link for **2nd page**, there have a **button** when click the button it add a *HTML row* on **1st page**. I am trying to use `localStorage` for passing data. My code don't work, take a look below:

> 1st Page.html

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var     output = document.getElementById('content');

addEvent(window, 'storage', function (event) {
  if (event.key == 'StorageName') {
    output.innerHTML = event.newValue;
  }
});
```

> 2nd Page.html

**HTML**

```
<input id="data" type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow()">
```

**JS**

```
addEvent(dataInput, 'keyup', function () {
localStorage.setItem('StorageName', this.value);
});

var dataInput = dataInput = document.getElementById('data');
object.onclick = function(){
addRow() {
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.className = 'row';

div.innerHTML = '<button>GO</button>';

document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
}
};
```

Comment: Your JS is hard to follow. For starters I don't see the addRow function defined anywhere. What actually happens when you click your button?

Comment: Have you followed your code in the step-debugger? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 3):

You haven't defined your `addRow()` function properly. A function's name is defined with the keyword `function`, not inside of the function body. Your code:

```
object.onclick = function(){
addRow() {
var div = document.createElement('div');

div.className = 'row';

div.innerHTML = '<button>GO</button>';

document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
}
};
```

Should be changed to:

```
function addRow() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = 'row';

    div.innerHTML = '<button>GO</button>';

    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);
}
object.onclick = addRow;
```

Comment: @pixelearth You deleted your answer and made it a comment of my answer, but I believe you meant to make it a comment of the actual question...

Comment: indeed, nice catch

Answer (score 0):

I agree with skyline3000's answer the addRow() should be defined. Also there are a few other things that could/should change:

- define dataInput before attaching an event to it
- object.onclick should be dataInput.onclick since thats the element being clicked. (is click event what you really want? maybe onkeyup?)
- when you set the localStorage you want to set the function definition being passed to Page 1 which appears to be addRow(). Simply remove the parenthesis to pass just the definition.(Should also be defined before using)
- If you want to just pass the function you shouldn't set the onclick event on Page 2. What you should probably do is record how many times you want it to run when you go to Page 1.
- You dont need to pass the function everytime if it isnt changing; Just set it once and record the number of times it was clicked.
- page 1 can catch the load event and the check localStorage for the function definition and number of times it was run. Then it can loop and perform the function.
- the code you have doesn't add a link back to page 2 if thats what you are looking for but you can add that into the addrow function when you know the file name and path.

### Page 1

```
var output = document.getElementById('content');

addEvent(window, 'load', function (event) {
  if (localStorage.getItem('StorageName') && localStorage.getItem('rowsToAdd')) {
    for(var i = 0; i > rowsToAdd;i++){
      var addNewRow = localStorage.getItem('StorageName');
      addNewRow();
     }
  }
});
```

### Page 2

```
var dataInput = document.getElementById('data');

function addRow() {
    var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className = 'row';

    div.innerHTML = '<button>GO</button>';

    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(div);

};
localStorage.setItem('StorageName', addRow);
dataInput.onclick = function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('rowsToAdd')){
        localStorage.setItem('rowsToAdd', localStorage.getItem('rowsToAdd') + 1); 
    }else{
        localStorage.setItem('rowsToAdd',1);
    }
}
```

I didn't test this code so it may not work copy+pasted but something pretty close hopefully.

I also answered this with the best understanding of what you wanted that I could manage but I dont fully see the desired result of what you seemed to be doing.

Comment: There are probably some null check that need to happen as well. maybe don't do anything until the document ready event is fired.